# What does ";" mean in this equation?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

What does ";" mean in this equation?

> y = f(x;θ)

or

[equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ8qq.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not programming question.

Answer (score 2):

`f(X;A)` means the function `f` is function of variables `X` , with regarding of the parameters `A`.

As an example, `F(X;A)= a*x^x+b*x+c` where  `X=[x]` is variable, and `A=[a,b,c]` are the parameters.